# Does height : auto for image stretch as much as the height of the png?

Tags: html, css

```
.q-team-images {
     width: 6.4rem;
     height: auto;
     padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }
```

Will the above css style make the image take the height as that of its png image's height?

Comment: changing the `width` will set the image width, and when used with `height: auto` will scale the height to be proportional to the width while maintaining the original image aspect ratio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Short Answer**

Setting either an image's `width` or `height` properties to a constant value and setting the other to `auto` will cause the image to scale to the constant value along the dimension specified while the other dimension scales to maintain the image's aspect ratio.

**The Longer Answer**

`width: auto;` or `height: auto;` normally just tells the element to scale to fit the dimensions of its child elements.

In the case of an HTML `<img>` tag, given a positive integer N, if `width: Npx;` and `height: auto;`, the image will have a width of `Npx` and a height scaled to maintain the aspect ratio. If `width: auto;` and `height: Npx`, the image will have a height of `Npx` and a width scaled to maintain the aspect ratio.

If both `height` and `width` are set to `auto`, the image will simply keep its default dimensions and maintain its aspect ratio.

See this codepen for proof: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbJgyy

The same behavior is also evident in this snippet:

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://mydirtsheet.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/rubber-duck_0.jpg?w=529"></img>
```

Comment: so, basically will it be a squared image?

Comment: If your original image is square, then changing one dimension to a constant value and setting the other to `auto` will essentially just scale the image up or down and maintain the aspect ratio, so the final image would be a square. If you want the image is not a square and you want it to be, just set both the `width` and `height` to a constant value. Otherwise, if the image is not a square and you set one of the dimensions to `auto`, the resulting scaled image will also not be a square, as it will just scale to match the aspect ratio of the original image.

Comment: If my png dimension of my image is 1920x1075. and if I set width :1020px and height:auto , will it work to maintain same aspect ratio of png image?

Comment: Yes. Another way to understand aspect ratios is to look at the math behind it. The current ratio of the image's width to height (width/height) is `1920 / 1075`, or about `1.78`. Now that you know the aspect ratio, you can use it to calculate the height of a properly scaled image with any given width. In this case, `1020px / 1.78 ≈ 573px`. So setting `width: 1020px;` and `height: auto;` basically means that the resulting image will have a height of approximately `573px`. The `auto` property when used on either width or height tells the browser to do this calculation for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if it doesn´t break the ratio of your image, since you have set a `width` it will scale in portion to your width so it might not (depending on your hight of the image.

You could also use `max-width` and `max-height`

```
.q-team-images {
    max-width: 1280px; //your images max width
    max-height: 720px; // your images max height
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes..It should change the height automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The height will be displayed in proportion to the width. It will keep the same ratio. So if the width is set to be larger than the initial width, the height will change proportional to the width.

Comment: So, will it maintain same aspect ratio for height and width ? like square images?

Comment: Yes, so if you have a vertical rectangle and you increase the width by 50%, the height will change automatically, so that it will look the same proportionally but larger with the width being 50%.  If it is a square and you increase the width by 50%, the height will increase by the same amount to keep the ratio, because a square has the same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not stretch, as proven by this snippet.

```css
.q-team-images {
     width: 6.4rem;
     height: auto;
     padding-bottom: 1rem;
 }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b253a5fdd8623bf89a90b706a313e27a?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" class="q-team-images">
<img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/21/e0/6e/21e06e09dc5ed981a0b3f9704bf459ee.jpg" class="q-team-images">
```

Comment: So,does it depend on content too? I mean suppose.if content is large enough to fill the space that image will be a square image, otherwise it will stretch to its maximum content length?

Comment: `auto` depends on context.  The wider the unmodified image is, the shorter the image will get and the width decreases in the unmodified image, the taller the image will get.  (assuming width remains constant in the modified image).  The only case that the image would be square is if it is originally square.